# Arranging items in a list

Tags: python, list

Description: 
Given a list, you want to look at the first element in that list and append all occurrences of that item to a new list and then move on the the next element and append all occurrences of that item to the new list and so forth.

Example: Give a list such as,

```
sample_list = [1,2,1,2]
```

You look at the first element in the list and we notice it's a 1, so we add all occurrences of that element to a new list and remove them from the sample list:

We now get:

```
new_list = [1,1]
sample_list = [2,2]
```

Now, we move on to the next element from the sample_list which is a 2, so we append all occurrences of that element to the new_list and remove them from the sample_list:

We now get:

```
new_list = [1, 1, 2, 2]
sample_list = []
```

In the end we return the new_list.

All of this must be accomplished **without** any use of importing modules.

Some examples and their expected outputs:

```
[1, 3, 3, 1, 1]
>>> [1, 1, 1, 3, 3]
['a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a']
>>> ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd']
['9', '6', '9', '3']
>>> ['9', '9', '6', '3']
```

Thank you for those who help

My horrible attempt at it:

```
def arrangement(sample_list):
    new_list = []
    item = sample_list[0]
    for element in sample_list:
        if element == item:
            new_list.append(element)
        else:
            pass
    for i in sample_list:
        if i != item:
            new_list.append(i)
        else:
            pass
    return new_list

>>> ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b']
['a', 'a', 'b', 'b']
>>> [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
>>> [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
>>> [1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2] # Fails here, I know why it failed but I can't figure out what to edit in code to fix this. Answer should be: [1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2]
```

Comment: What is this trend of people copy-pasting their homework to Stack Overflow? Show us what progress you did, and where specifically you are having trouble.

Comment: @Amadan On the plus side it does include code formatting - so some effort has gone into it :)

Comment: It actually isn't copy-pasting =p, this is something I've been stuck on for some time but I tried to do my best to explain what I was trying to achieve, that's why it might seem as though it appears copy-pasted. I'll post what I got so far.

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Counter

sample_list = [1, 2, 1, 2]

def arrangement(lst):
    lookup = Counter(lst)
    result = []
    for item in lst:
        try:
            num = lookup.pop(item)
            result.extend(item for i in range(num))
        except KeyError:
            pass
    return result

if __name__=="__main__":
    print sample_list, arrangement(sample_list)
```

Comment: A somewhat contrived requirement from the OP is "no imports"

Comment: @1_CR: (shrug) well, I wouldn't want to do *all* his homework for him ;-)

Comment: interesting use of `Counter`, +1 :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use the pop() function, which is detailed in python docs.